# React Laravel Project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, load, production

I am working on a react/Laravel application, and i faced some problems running it in production, the application takes a lot of time to load cuz the app.js file is **8mb** and  this is huge plus considering that the application itself is not so big , I'm not familiar on react/Laravel applications and don't know exactly how the Laravel mix bundles the app, or maybe i am missing any configuration in weback.mix.js file

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.react()
.extract(["react"])
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

Thank you in advance, would be a big HELP for me if anyone can help.

Comment: The size of the app.js will be affected by your dependencies; react alone won't make it 8mb, so start looking at your `package.json` file. https://www.jakepusateri.com/blog/find-the-big-dependency/ has information on finding what's causing it to be so big.

Comment: Also, when deploying to production, be sure you're minifying. This can dramatically reduce file size.

Comment: how are you building the app?

Comment: So i have this  "production": "mix --production" in package.json
and i build app running npm run production.

Comment: Try [webpack bundle analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer). Instructions how to add custom config are [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#custom-webpack-configuration)

Comment: So i was using this 'react-rainbow-components' and this thing is really huge, removing it saved me 4 mb.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to build the JS file for production.
use the production **env** command : `npm run production`

also check if you are loading useless css or js files, for example if ypu are using bootstrap 4 in your app, check that you are using mini version of them and only the files that you need are being used.